# Can correlation dimension of an attractor exceed the dimension of the space?

Tags: correlation, dimension-theory-analysis, chaos-theory

Here is the definition of the correlation dimension:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_dimension

Is there a proof that the correlation dimension cannon exceed the dimension of the space?